# Splicing a Pandas dataframe by column name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to split a copy off of a Pandas dataframe starting after a certain column by header name.

So far, I've been able to manipulate the column headers or indexes according to a set number of known columns, like below. However, the number of columns will change, and I want to still extract every column that happens after.

In the below example, say I want to grab all columns after 'Tail' even if the 'Body' columns goes to column *X*. So the below sample with *X* number of Body columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Intro1': ['blah'],
            'Intro2': ['blah'],'Intro3': ['blah'],'Body1': ['blah'],'Body2': ['blah'],'Body3': ['blah'],'Body4': ['blah'], ... 'BodyX': ['blah'],'Tail': ['blah'],'OtherTail': ['blah'],'StillAnotherTail': ['blah'],})
```

Should produce a copy of the dataframe as:

```
dftail = pd.DataFrame({'Tail': ['blah'],'OtherTail': ['blah'],'StillAnotherTail': ['blah'],})
```

Ideally I'd like to find a way to combine the two techiques below so that the column starts at 'Tail' and goes to the end of the dataframe:

```
dftail = [col for col in df if col.startswith('Tail')]

dftail = df.iloc[:, 164:] # column number (164) will change based on 'Tail' index number
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
df_tail = df.iloc[:, list(df.columns).index("Tail"):]
```

`df_tail` then prints out:

```
    Tail    OtherTail   StillAnotherTail
0   blah    blah        blah
```

Comment: Slightly more plain syntax `df.columns.get_loc('Tail'):`